CSE - How to avoid partial search for the term
I think every individual word supposed not be able to be partially matched, but we got a weird result for the following example
We got a doc for this example: ((Ganni OR #GanniGirls OR Reformation)) which only matched the word reformed instead of reformation , should we always double quotes every term? in case it will partial match
